# Trying to filter values to a People or group field that has multiple values. Tried Both CAML and REST

Tags: rest, caml, multiple-values, person

I have a list called Teams that has 2 columns, 'Title' and 'Team Members'.
Team Members is a Person or Group Field that allows multiple values.
There are 3 Teams defined in the list with multiple users in each team. I am a member of 2 of the teams.

***What I am trying to do is query this list and return only the Teams that the current user is a member of.*** I have attempted to do this with REST and with JavaScript SharePoint Client context.  Here's what I have so far.

**REST API Attempt**

```
    function GetTeams(userId) {
    var res;
    var requestURL = config.SiteURL + '/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'' + config.Library + '\')/items?$select=Title,Team_x0020_MembersId';
    $.ajax({
        url: requestURL,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },
        method: 'GET',
        //Success Function
        success: function (data) {
            res = data.d.results;
            console.log('This is a list of all the teams');
            console.log(res);
            var teammembers = res[0].Team_x0020_MembersId.results;
            console.log('This is just the Team Member IDs of the first team in the array ' + teammembers);
        },
        //Error Function
        error: function (jQxhr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
            res = jQxhr;
            console.log(res);

        },
        dataType: 'json' //Make me a JSON
    });
};
```

This will return all the teams. I have tried to use $filter=Team_x0020_MembersID eq userID with no success.

**CLIENT CONTEXT ATTEMPT**

```
var ctx;
var web;
var user;
var teams;
var items;

function sharePointReady(){
  var cQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

  ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  web=ctx.get_web();
  ctx.load(web);
  user=web.get_currentUser();

  teams = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Teams');
  cQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Where><Includes><FieldRef Name='Team_x0020_Members' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Integer'>9057</Value></Includes></Where></View>");

  items = teams.getItems(cQuery);
  ctx.load(items);
  console.log(items);
  console.log(cQuery);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);

}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    console.log('current user id ' + user.get_id());

    var itemInfo='';
    var TeamMembers;
    var itemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    while(itemEnumerator.moveNext()){
        var li = itemEnumerator.get_current();
        itemInfo += '\n' + li.get_id();
        itemInfo += '\t' + li.get_item('Title');
        itemInfo += '\t' + li.get_item('Team_x0020_Members');
        TeamMembers=li.get_item('Team_x0020_Members');
        console.log('Team Member Array');
        console.log(TeamMembers);
        console.log('Individual Team Members');
        for(i=0; i< TeamMembers.length;i++)
            {
                console.log(TeamMembers[i].$1E_1);
            }

    }
}

function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
console.clear();
sharePointReady();
```

This again returns all 3 teams instead of just the 2 teams that the current user (me) is a member of.

In short.. does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and can you help me query just the teams that the current logged in user is a member of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could construct the following CAML query to *return only the Teams that the current user is a member of*:

```
<Or>
  <Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\">
    <FieldRef Name=\"Team_x0020_Members\"/>
  </Membership>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name=\"Team_x0020_Members\"></FieldRef>
    <Value Type=\"Integer\">
      <UserID/>
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Or>
```

Follow [`Membership Element (Query)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544234(v=office.15).aspx) for a more details

**REST example**

Both REST and JSOM APIs supports CAML queries, the below example shows how to utilize CAML query via REST endpoint:

```
var listTitle = "Teams";

var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";
var queryXml = "\
<View> \
   <Query> \
      <Where> \
          <Or> \
            <Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\">  \
                <FieldRef Name=\"Team_x0020_Members\"/> \
            </Membership> \
            <Eq> \
                <FieldRef Name=\"Team_x0020_Members\"></FieldRef> \
                   <Value Type=\"Integer\">  \
                        <UserID/> \
                   </Value> \
           </Eq>  \
         </Or> \
      </Where> \
   </Query> \
</View>";


var queryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
           'ViewXml': queryXml
        } 
}; 



executeJson({
        "url" :url,
        "method": 'POST',
        "data": queryPayload})
.done(function(items)
{
    items.d.results.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item.Title); 
    });
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    var method = options.method || "GET";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if("data" in options) {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

Comment: Very concise and it works great.  Thank you for the response I should be able to modify this to my needs nicely!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

First get the current user Login name using the below function

```
var UserName;
function CallClientOM()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.website = context.get_web();
this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
context.load(currentUser);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}



function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
 {
 alert(currentUser.get_loginName());
 UserName = currentUser.get_loginName()
 }
```

Then apply filter as follows:

```
$filter=='Your Internal field name for Team Members' eq 
               'UserName'"
```

Hope that helps.